# Wsus Updates View

Tags: wsus

I have the WSUS server/admin console installed on my server A and the admin console installed on my computer A. Both of them are connected to server A.
When i create an Update View on my computer admin console, it doesn't appear on my server admin console. 
But if i create a computer group it replicates.

Is it the way it should behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. views are computer specific. groups are not because updates can be applied to groups, so the server needs to know about those groups.